# Replacing the values of a categorical variable using if-else condition or any other approach

Tags: r, if-statement, r-factor

This is my dataset “Survey” which contains “Codes” as a categorical variable.

```
ID<- seq(1:50)
Codes<- sample(c("Sat1", "Sat2", "A1", "B2", "C2", "D5", "T4"), 50, replace= TRUE)
Survey<- data.frame(Codes)
```

The levels in Codes are shown as follows:

```
> levels(Survey$Codes)
[1] "A1"   "B2"   "C2"   "D5"   "Sat1" "Sat2" "T4"
```

I want to replace all the values in Codes column except “Sat1” and “Sat2” with a new value “Sat3”. In other words, I expect my levels in Codes to be:

```
> levels(Survey$Codes)
[1] “Sat1” “Sat2” “Sat3”
```

I know the first part of code to this problem i.e.

```
levels(Survey$Codes)<- c(levels(Survey$Codes), “Sat3”)
```

but I am stuck how to proceed with the rest of the code i.e. how to replace all the values of Codes (except “Sat1” and “Sat2”) with “Sat3”. I am thinking to use an if-else statement here but not sure how to frame the codes for it. Could you please help me with this? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about

```
levels(Survey$Codes)[!grepl("Sat",levels(Survey$Codes))]<-"Sat3"
```

grepl checks if a certain string occurs in your levels. Output:

```
> levels(Survey$Codes)
[1] "Sat3" "Sat1" "Sat2"

> Survey$Codes
 [1] Sat3 Sat1 Sat3 Sat2 Sat3 Sat3 Sat3 Sat3 Sat3 Sat3 Sat3 Sat3 Sat1 Sat3 Sat2 Sat3 Sat1 Sat3 Sat1 Sat2 Sat3 Sat3 Sat3 Sat2 Sat3
[26] Sat1 Sat3 Sat3 Sat3 Sat3 Sat3 Sat3 Sat3 Sat2 Sat3 Sat3 Sat1 Sat3 Sat3 Sat3 Sat3 Sat2 Sat3 Sat3 Sat3 Sat2 Sat3 Sat3 Sat3 Sat3
Levels: Sat3 Sat1 Sat2
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the data frame you wanted to create was:

```
Survey <- data.frame(ID = seq(1:50),
                    Codes = sample(c("Sat1", "Sat2", "A1", "B2", "C2", "D5", "T4"), 50, replace= TRUE))
```

One solution to your problem would be to add a new level called "Sat3":

```
levels(Survey$Codes)<- c(levels(Survey$Codes), "Sat3")
Survey$Codes[!grepl("Sat1|Sat2", Survey$Codes)] <- "Sat3" #replace if level is either Sat1 or Sat2
```

If you want, you can drop unused factor levels after that:

```
Survey$Codes <- droplevels(Survey$Codes)
```

Comment: Works great. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
levels(Survey$Codes)[!levels(Survey$Codes) %in% c("Sat1", "Sat2")]<- "Sat3"

#> levels(Survey$Codes)
#[1] "Sat3" "Sat1" "Sat2"
```

Note that this is a more general solution. For example, if the levels of interest do not have any character in common, the `grepl` solution won't work.

Comment: This is the simple logic I was looking for.